# Palindrome program and Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, valgrind

Similar questions have been asked. This problem is the common finding the longest palindrome sub-string.

Having some problems reading the error dump, I think I have an array index out of bound error, but not able to trace it using my logs, output statements and reviewing my condition checking too. Added comments to denote line numbers. Running this on the Linux subsystem for Windows.

**Output**

```
> valgrind --track-origins=yes ./a.out
==665== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==665== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==665== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==665== Command: ./a.out
==665==
==665== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
==665== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==665==    at 0x401C00: Solution::longestPalindrome(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (main.cpp:61)
==665==    by 0x400F05: main (main.cpp:79)
==665==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==665==    at 0x401752: Solution::longestPalindrome(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (main.cpp:28)
==665==
aaaabbaa HAS: aabbaa <-
```

**Code**

```
class Solution
{
    public:
        std::pair<int,int> expandFrom(const std::string s, int left_char, int right_char, const int str_len)
        {
            while(left_char >= 0 && right_char <= str_len && s[left_char] == s[right_char]) {
                --left_char;
                ++right_char;
            }

            return {left_char+1, right_char-1};
        }

        const std::string longestPalindrome(const std::string s) // line 28
        {
            if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() >= 1000) { return ""; }
            else if(s.length() == 1) { return s; }

            const int str_length = s.length();
            std::string longest_palindrome = "";

            std::pair<int, int> range1 = {0,0};
            std::pair<int, int> range2 = {0,0};
            int length1 = 0;
            int length2 = 0;

            for(int mid = 0; mid < str_length; ++mid) {
                range1 = expandFrom(s, mid, mid, str_length);
                range2 = expandFrom(s, mid, mid+1, str_length);
                length1 = range1.second - range1.first;
                length2 = range2.second - range2.first;
                if (length1 > length2) {
                    if (length1 > longest_palindrome.length()) {
                        longest_palindrome = s.substr(range1.first, range1.second);
                        if(longest_palindrome[range1.first] != longest_palindrome[range1.second]) {
                            longest_palindrome = s.substr(range1.first, range1.second + 1);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (length2 > longest_palindrome.length()) { // line 61
                        longest_palindrome = s.substr(range2.first, range2.second);
                        if(longest_palindrome[range2.first] != longest_palindrome[range2.second]) {
                            longest_palindrome = s.substr(range2.first, range2.second + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return longest_palindrome;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Solution s;
    std::cout << "aaaabbaa HAS: " << s.longestPalindrome("aaaabbaa") << " <-\n\n"; // line 79    
}
```

Comment: what is `longest_palindrome` missing in your code ?

Comment: good catch added back, copy past error

Comment: the posted code is C++, not C.  Please remove the 'c' tag

Comment: which line is 28?  which line is 61?

Comment: Shouldn't be right_char<str_length in ExpandFrom?

Comment: @user3629249 added line number comments

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but important nonetheless: you should never return a `const` object from a function. In the best case it does nothing, but in the worst case someone will write `std::string s = longestPalindrome(foo)` and incur one unnecessary string copy. It also doesn't make sense semantically: you don't own the return value after you've returned, yet you insist it not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic is clearly wrong...

Your code executes the statement:

```
longest_palindrome = s.substr(range2.first, range2.second);
```

so `longest_palindrome` now is a string of length `range2.second - range2.first` and valid indexes go from `0` to `range2.second - range2.first - 1` included.

In the next statement however you're accessing it using `range2.first` and `range2.second` as indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm having some difficulty understanding what the correct logic could be. Is there any advice you can share on how I can correct my logic?

Comment: I'd say that in the `IF`s following the `longest_palindrome` assignment you should still use `s` instead of `longest_palindrome`; e.g. `if(s[range1.first] != s[range1.second]) ...`. Indeed may be the logic is not "wrong" but you just slipped the variable name to use in the IF.